# What are the steps for factorizing $1 - ab - cd + abcd$?

Tags: factoring

I can see that $1 - ab - cd + abcd$ factors to $(1-cd)(1-ab)$ but only because I tried a lot of different factors in a trial and error method, so it took me a while. I was wondering what the pattern to observe is and what the general/efficient method for factoring something like this is?

Comment: $1-ab-cd-abcd$ does not factor to $(1-cd)(1-ab)$, because $(1-cd)(1-ab)=1-ab-cd+abcd$.

Comment: @Florian: Woops, typo. Thanks. (fixed)

Comment: how about 1(1-ab) - cd(1-ab);  then factor out a (1-ab) to get (1-ab)(1-cd)?

Comment: I guess practice more problems then you'll see

Comment: The pattern to observe would probably be $(1-x)(1-y)=1-x-y+xy$.

Comment: Another heuristic that works here: You can factorize any expression with 4 terms if the sum of the 2nd and the 3rd terms equals the product of the first and the 4th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are usually called "factoring by grouping."  As all factoring is basically educated trial-and-error, you should be encouraged that you found the correct factorization.  Anyway, here's more detail about factoring by grouping:

$$
\begin{align*}
  1 - ab - cd + abcd &= (1-ab) - (cd - abcd) \\
  &= (1-ab) - cd(1 - ab) \\
  &= (1-ab)(1-cd).
\end{align*}
$$
The crucial steps are: finding groups that look very similar -- with a goal of factoring a gcd from each group.  If each group now contains the same expression in parentheses, then that expression can be factored out.

Hope this helps!